# Why is rails creating and undefined select option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, angularjs

view.erb

```
<select ng-model="integration.connector_one">
  <%=options_for_select(connectors, connectors[0])%>
</select>
```

Produces:

```
<select ng-model="integration.connector_one" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Shopify</option>
  <option value="8">Spreadsheet</option>
  <option value="9">Pardot</option>
  <option value="10">Spreadsheet</option>
  <option value="11">Spreadsheet</option>
  <option value="12">Pardot</option>
</select>
```

Connectors is:

```
[["Shopify", 1], ["Spreadsheet", 8], ["Pardot", 9], ["Spreadsheet ", 10], ["Spreadsheet ", 11], ["Pardot", 12]]
```

How can i prevent the undefined option from being created?

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `options_for_select` is the optional `selected` parameter, which is either a single value, or in the case of multiple select elements, and array of values to be selected. In this case, it's looking for options with values `Shopify` and `1` and marking those selected. Since it's not finding `Shopify` (as a value), you're getting the undefined element.

Change `connectors[0]` to `connectors[0][1]` to just pass the value of the first option.

Comment: made no difference. still have the undefined option. also if I leave out the select parameter i still have the undefined option.

Comment: You're right; I just ran this in the console and both methods are working fine. Is there any JavaScript on the page that could be inserting this?

Comment: Yeah.. i'm trying to use angularJS. I removed the model definition and it cleared it up... think i need to us ngOptions in angular and not actually use options_for_select